# Downvoted four times within a minute - serial downvoting?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, serial-voting

I checked my rep today and I noticed I was down some points. Somebody has downvoted my question four times within 1 minute:

[image: Reputation change - evil downvote]

Is this *already* serial downvoting? Will it be corrected by a rep-recalculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably is.

Wait until the anti-serial voting script runs (It usually runs at 3AM, but wait at least 24~48 hours). If it isn't reversed automatically, put it up in the respective site's meta or flag one of the post for moderator attention.